# I need to extract text after = for each value seperated by semicolon in javascript. I have done it but wondering if there is a better approach

Tags: javascript

My working code:

```js
const myString = "a=*aaa;b=*bbb";
let params = [];
myString.split(";").forEach(element => {
  let zz = element.split('=');
  params.push(zz[1]);
});
console.log(params.map((element, index) => index + '=' + element).join(';'));
```

Comment: Better approach is "broad" term. Better at what?

Comment: Do you care about the a and b? Do you just need the values?

Comment: I just need the values separated by semicolon (e.g *aaa;*bbb)

Comment: `"a=*aaa;b=*bbb".split(/[=;]/).map((s, i) => i % 2 ? s : null).filter(Boolean)` or  `"a=*aaa;b=*bbb".split(/[=;]/).reduce((a, v, i) => ((i % 2 && a.push(v)), a), []).join(';')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You can make `params` a const

It is an array, and you are just appending items.

#### You can merge the two statements in the loop

You are `let`ting a variable, and then just using it once.

#### You can convert the whole process into a `.map`

Instead of creating an empty array and appending things to it, you can map the array of ";" separated strings into a corresponding array of the strings you want.

#### Applying all 3 steps, you get this:

```js
const myString = "a=*aaa;b=*bbb";

const params = myString.split(";").map(
  element => element.split('=')[1]
);

console.log(params.map((element, index) => index + '=' + element).join(';'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter approach, but think about if you want an approach like that. It is not easy to read.

```js
const myString = "a=*aaa;b=*bbb";

const params =
  myString
  .split(";")
  .map((element, index) => {
    let zz = element.split('=');

    return `${index}=${element.split("=")[1]}`;
  })
  .join(";");

console.log(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put them in an object.

```
const myString = "a=*aaa;b=*bbb";
let params = {};
myString.split(";").forEach(element => {
  let zz = element.split('=');
  params[zz[0]] = zz[1];
});
console.log(params);
```